# reseting color of button in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, tic-tac-toe

I am new in android studio. I am making Tic Tac toe and when I am clicking on button, it's changes its background color and text.

```
clickedView.text = "x"
clickedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)
```

this is button in .XML file:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="45pt"
        android:layout_width="45pt"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
```

so, now i am making reset button and i dont know how to change button's background color on default. can you help me with that?

Comment: The button has no memory of its original color. You just have to manually change to the color you want using the same `setBackgroundColor` function.

Comment: thanks but i just use "R.color"  to fint dint my default colors in styles's xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the color from **hex code**

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Or get it from the **resources**

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
```

Or from **default colors**

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```